# Load a specific jsp page in another jsp page when select item on combobox using jQuery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I need some help with ajax load method.
I have a `index.jsp` page that the top of the page shows a combobox with `id="operation"  name="showOperation"` tag and lower a container div with `id="showOperation"` in which to load a specific page from servlet jsp choice.
Basically what I want is that when I select an item on the combobox, the request is sent directly to the servlet with the chosen value (without pressing any button). The servlet responds to the request with something like this:

```
if(req.getParameter("operation").equalsIgnoreCase("add")){ // add is a choice of the combobox
    req.setAttribute("toLoad", "add-page.jsp");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp); 
}
if(req.getParameter("operation").equalsIgnoreCase("sub")){ 
    req.setAttribute("toLoad", "sub-page.jsp");
    req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, resp); 
}
```

Now, if I choose the add item on combobox, the `add-page.jsp` partial page is loaded directly in my `index.jsp` main page inside:

```
<div id="showOperation"></div>
```

I tried to use this jQuery code:

```
<head>
    <script scr="JS/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#operation").click(function(event){
                $('#showOperation').load('????');
            });
        });
     </script>
</head>
```

but I do not know whether it is the correct solution, and if it is, what argument to pass to the `.load('????');` method..

**SOLVED:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#operation').off();
    $('#operation').on('change', function(){
        $("#showOperation").empty();
        var servletUrl = "Servlet?operation="+$('#operation option:selected').val();
        $("#showOperation").load(servletUrl, function(response, status, xhr){
            if (status == "success"){
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check jQuery documentation for [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method,

You can use simple url as a parameter,

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the selected value from select on change, you can do it as:

```
$('#operation').on('change', function() {
  alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

`load` function loads data from the server and place the returned HTML into the element.
so, you can do it like this:

```
$('#operation').change(function() {    
    var item=$(this);
    $("#showOperation").empty();
    $("#showOperation").load("servletURL?param="+item.attr("value"));
});
```

make sure your servlet return the html as required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use your code but when I select an item on the combobox nothing happens. The servlet does not enter even in the loop `if(req.getParameter("operation") != null){...}`. My Form code: `<form name="operation" id="operation" action="Servlet" method="get"><select id="operation" name="operation"><option value="add">add</option><option value="sub">sub</option></select></form>`. What I doing wrong?